# how to add to current fs ext4

Tags: debian, ext4, resize2fs

So I deleted my windows partition and now I'm trying to add to the currant partition but it's not letting me either through GParted or KDE part.. any suggestions?

```
:caspah@debian:~$ sudo lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
mmcblk0      179:0    0 116.5G  0 disk 
├─mmcblk0p1  179:1    0    16M  0 part 
├─mmcblk0p2  179:2    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─mmcblk0p3  179:3    0  74.8G  0 part 
├─mmcblk0p4  179:4    0  39.1G  0 part /
├─mmcblk0p5  179:5    0   700M  0 part 
├─mmcblk0p6  179:6    0   200M  0 part 
└─mmcblk0p7  179:7    0   977M  0 part [SWAP]
mmcblk0boot0 179:256  0     4M  1 disk 
mmcblk0boot1 179:512  0     4M  1 disk
```

also is it safe to get rid of the `/boot/efi` parition along with the ASUS and microsfot recovery?

Comment: which partition is the ex-windows partition? is it `mmcblk0p3`?   and you want to add its space to the rootfs on `mmcblk0p4`?

Answer (score 0):

Explain what kind of error it is showing when you try. You cannot extend a partition when it is mounted. You probably need to use a live USB.

Removing `/boot/efi` will make your system stop booting. It is usually a FAT32 contains EFI files  for booting in UEFI, because your computers cannot read ext partition directly. It contains your bootloader (GRUB2 or systemd-boot).

Removing recovery partition will disable you from restoring Asus-provided MS-Win, although you can install in regular way.

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING:** The following assumes that the ex-Windows partition is `mmcblk0p3` and you want to add its space to the Linux rootfs on `mmcblk0p4`.   If this is not the case, then adapt to suit your actual needs.

This is possible, but slightly complicated because p3 is before p4 on the disk.

Firstly, you may have erased all the data on mmcblk0p3 but you haven't actually deleted the partition from the partition table.  You'll need to do that first.  Boot up a [GParted Live](https://gparted.org/) CD or USB and delete it.

Then move `mmcblk0p4` to where `mmcblk0p3` used to be (so that all the empty space is **after** your rootfs instead of before it) and, finally, tell `gparted` to expand that partition to add all the empty, un-partitioned space that is now after it.

---

BTW, it's been a while since I've done this, so I can't remember if `gparted` will renumber `mmcblk0p4` as `mmcblk0p3` or not when you move it.  I think it doesn't....but **if and ONLY if it does**, you'll need to update grub's configuration in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` so that it knows the root fs is on `mmcblk0p3` now: You'd need to do something like this (from a root shell while still running from the GParted Live CD):

```
mount /dev/mmcblk0p3 /mnt
for i in proc dev sys ; do mount -o bind /$i /mnt/$i ; done
chroot /mnt
### optionally edit /etc/fstab here
update-grub
exit
for i in proc dev sys / ; do umount /mnt/$i ; done
```

NOTE: If you hard-coded the device names in `/etc/fstab` (instead of using LABEL or UUID entries), you will also have to edit `/etc/fstab` with `vi` or `nano` or whatever to change the device name for `/`. Do this after the `chroot /mnt` and before the `update-grub`.

You'll probably need to change the device name for the SWAP partition too, if that also got renumbered.  Same for any other partitions used or mounted from `/etc/fstab` entries.

Comment: I should have mentioned: if you have **any** important data on the machine then, before doing anything else, **make a backup of your system disk**.   It's only ~120 GB, so can fit on a relatively cheap USB stick.   You can probably use the gparted cd to do the backup, or you may find it easier to use [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/), which can not only make & restore clone backups of disk images, it can also automatically compress and uncompress them (so your system might even fit on a 64GB or smaller USB stick)

Comment: So i got it to resize, but now it won't boot. I musta somehow deleted the /boot/efi..but in the granted liveCD the ext3 is still there and incan mount /dev/mmcblk0p4 /mnt and it's still all there..is there anyway rewrite the /boot/efi partition? Somehow mmcblk0p7 was moved up ahead of mmcblk0p5 and mmcblk0p2 and mmcblk0p3 are gone.. am I screwed?

Comment: It's probably fixable if your machine (presumably some kind of tablet or laptop???) came with a CD or USB stick installer, that lets you restore it to factory condition (backup your linux partition first!).  Or if you know someone with the same model, you should be able to make a copy of their /boot/efi partition and restore it to yours...then you'll need to re-install grub to be able to boot linux.   As a last resort, see if the shop you bought it from can restore it (again, backup your linux partition and any other important data **before** taking it in for repair).